# How to concat text in Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want to concat two text and display with single TextView in Android. I have tried following type. It displays in logcat only, but it isn't concat in XML textview.

Here is my code:

```
<TextView
              android:id="@+id/heizgriffe"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Heizgriffe"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"

              android:layout_below="@+id/txt"/>
```

in Java class:

```
txtConcat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
String hub="Hubraum:";
            String str= ItemList.getTxt(); // fetting from webservice
            txtConcat .setText(hub + str );
```

Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txtConcat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt); // initialize
String hub="Hubraum:";
String str= ItemList.getTxt(); // fetching from webservice
txtConcat .setText(hub + str );
```

Comment: sorry i m using like this only but its not concat

Comment: string concatenate is working fine in relative layout, but its not working under linear layout. any body know the reason for that issue?

Comment: now its working, here i am wrongly put txtConcat.setText() in two times, so only that time its not working

Answer (score 2):

What you intend to do is not as complicated as you see, it is true that the result you are getting is not what you want, looking at your code I can say that not even the program should compile because it must be generating a syntax error. This is because you cannot concatenate the text using setText. The solution can be the following.

XML file:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="TextView" />
```

Java Class:

```
public TextView tvInfo;
private java.lang.CharSequence ID = "8945213624";

TextView tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
tvInfo.setText("My ID number is: ");
tvInfo.append(ID);
```

The result is as follows:

My ID number is: 8945213624

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just have to make proper use of the elements of concatenation, in this case that I show I use append to be able to concatenate the elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try This Answer........

```
String hub="Hubraum:";
String str= hub+ItemList.getTxt(); // fetcting from webservice
txtConcat.setText(str );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str= (String) ItemList.getTxt();
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

txtConcat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

Shouldn't it be: 
txtConcat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.heizgriffe);